# How can I find 5 doc with highest score facet with certain field within doc?

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase

I am using Couchbase which is Nosql database to store data for a website. Also I am using Elasticsearch as my querying tool. I recently encountered a challenge on facet or grouping result. Say I have 7 doc in my db

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "keywords": "red",
  "owner_id": "a"
}

{
  "id": "2", 
  "keywords": "red",  
  "owner_id": "a"
}

{
  "id": "3",
  "keywords": "red",  
  "owner_id": "a"
}

{
  "id": "4",
  "keywords": "red blue green",  
  "owner_id": "a"
}

{
  "id": "5",
  "keywords": "red blue",  
  "owner_id": "b"
}

{
  "id": "6",
  "keywords": "red blue",  
  "owner_id": "b"
}

{
  "id": "7",
  "keywords": "red blue green yellow",  
  "owner_id": "b"
}
```

when I search for `"red"` in `"keywords"`, I will get 6 result each one with a score. order like:

```
1
2
3
5
6
4
7
```

What I want is I search for `"red"` in `"keywords"`, and I add facet term `"owner_id"`, facet size of 2. It returns me just

```
1
2
5
6
```

which means even id "3" scores higher than "5" and "6" in terms of matching `"red"`, but since it reaches max number of doc can be returned from type "a", it wont be returned

I've tried facets, but it only gives me stats at the end, still returns all the docs. I read about aggregations in 1.00 beta2, still cant find a way through. Any ideas on I can do it all in one query?

Comment: What database are you using?  Also, how are you doing your searched? Please edit your question to add the appropriate tag and what code/queries you are using to do the searches.

Comment: I think his question is "how can i show only the top two results for each term" where term is owner_id in this case. I don't think you can do that in elasticsearch in a single query. You can though create a search with terms facets loop through the available terms and then do the top x results for each of those terms (which could be a lot of hits to search)

Comment: I think James got me right, the question should be "how can I show only the top two results for each term". I thought about to loop all available terms then compare the score to get the order. But the thing is I've already have 1000 terms which means 1000 queries for one action. And there might be many people want to do same action at the same time.